# Parse Cloud Code Queries Return Nothing

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to use Cloud Code on Parse to delete pre-existing rows as new rows are added.

This is the current code I've put together:

```
var queryGoals = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend('Goal'));
queryGoals.include('user');
queryGoals.equalTo('user', request.user);

queryGoals.find({
    success: function(results) {
        console.warn('Query Returned: ' + results.length);
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        console.warn('Error ' + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
    }
});
```

The console never shows the number of records returned (I assume because none are), nor any errors. The same code (with `Parse.User.current()` for the user filter, of course) returns the expected number of rows when run client-side.

Do queries operate differently when executed by Cloud Code, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: I do not believe you can send objects directly up to cloud code functions, you must sound up the object id of the object and then create an object from that in cloud code and query against it.

Comment: @Jacob it is ok to get the user from `request.user`. @Cameron Are you sure that this cloud function is called? You can check from the cloud code logs. Put some `console.log` in your code. Remove `equalTo` condition to check if it returns all the Goals, then log the user and add `equalTo`. Try to debug your code.

Comment: @knshn that would be for the current user, yes.

Comment: The success block will get fired with an empty array if nothing matches your query, so at a minimum you would get "Query Returned: 0" in your server-side console.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all. Parse's log shows the function being called. I omitted it from the snippet in my question for brevity, but I do have a line immediately before `queryGoals.find({...})` for logging to the console, which does show up (albeit after the log entries for each cloud function being called). There were other query filters/constraints that I had already taken out, but removing the user constraint too doesn't seem to have had any effect.

Comment: If you have ACL restrictions on your data, you must call `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` in the beginning of your cloud code function

Comment: All of the objects in the class being queried have both read and write ACL restrictions. I added your line at the very beginning of the `beforeSave` method, and, when it had no apparent effect, I added `useMasterKey: true` as an option to the query. Should I be doing something else in addition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I filed a bug report with Parse and finally ended up finding out that the function was ending before the success function was executed since it was running asynchronously. I added in the proper promise structure to get it working as expected ([Additional Details](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/)):

```
queryGoals.find(
{
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(results)
    {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
    },
    error: function(user, error)
    {
        console.warn('Error ' + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
    }
}).then(
    function(object)
    {
        // Do Post-Query Stuff Here
        response.success();
    },
    function(error)
    {
        console.warn('Error ' + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
    }
);
```